# Help icons on profile page, linking to related meta posts/articles

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, profile-page, recent-activity

It could be a good idea to have little red question marks by some of the areas of the profile/activity page that you could click on to get meta threads related to that area.

So, if I'm wondering about what does that whole flag weight thing mean, I click on the little red question mark in its vicinity, and I get a list of pertinent meta information (similar to the box that comes up with "related questions" after I typed in the title of my post today).

I can surmise that the more experienced members might be annoyed with further screen clutter, but I think it would help those of us learning the ropes to connect the material available on the two sites together.

Comment: As an aside: sometimes it helps to limit your search to posts that have been tagged `faq`, like by searching for "[faq] flag weight" or even simply "[faq flag weight](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=faq+flag+weight)".

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know. And thanks for the edit, too.

Comment: To reduce chance of "might be annoyed with further screen clutter" it's possible to implement such feature only for <1K rep users or something like this. :)